# Select ONLY field names from table WITHOUT information_schema

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I can execute the queries:

`SELECT COLUMNS FROM _table-name_` ...or... `SELECT COLUMNS FROM _table-name_`

Which will give the example result of:

`+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+
| Field | Type   | Null | Key | Default |
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+
| id    | char   | no   | pri | (NULL)  |
+       +        +      +     +         +
| name  | char   | no   |     | (NULL)  |
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+`

This is OK but I only want the `Field` column. I have seen solutions where you can query `information_schema` but, unfortunately, I do **not** have that option to me so I am looking for a solution along the lines of

`SELECT Field FROM (SHOW COLUMNS FROM _table-name_)`
*(but I know this is not possible)*

Also, this needs to be possible in one query.

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by MySQL is to use information_schema. You need to explain why this is not an option for you, and what you're trying to achieve, if anyone can suggest an alternative.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='myschema' AND TABLE_NAME='mytable'
```

You can query the I_S tables using a qualified tablename (as I show above) even if your default schema is currently some other schema.

You always have privileges to read I_S. If you have privileges to read the tables in your specified schema, you can read the corresponding rows of metadata from I_S tables.

Comment: The problem being that the backend targets a specific db in some old legacy code that we dare not touch. I could rewire it to target the I_S as well but it'd be more hassle than it's worth and the code will, more than likely, never be reused. If the proper (only) way to do it is to target I_S then I guess that's what I'll have to do

Comment: By "targets" do you mean the code sets a default database? Any query can reference tables from other schemas (like I_S), and can even mix-and-match tables from different schemas in the same query. That's what qualified table names are for. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Comment: Yes by "targets" I mean that the code sets a default database. For instance, say my db was *db_1* and I was to do a query in the code, the query would just be like: `SELECT * FROM table_in_db_1` as I do not need to reference the db. So this is like a config but a config that I would rather not tamper with and, from what I have just read, I don't think qualifiers would work in this instance